# How do I configure Ruby alone with Apache + FastCGI?

Tags: ruby, apache, fastcgi

There are many how-to's for people who want to use Rails with Apache and fastcgi. But I need to use Ruby alone without any frameworks (for educational purpose). So does anyone know how to configure Apache with FastCGI and to write a simple "Hello world"-style dispatcher on Ruby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at https://serverfault.com/posts/106607/revisions

Comment: Thanks a lot, but maybe more explanation about Apache configuration will be great